# How to print DOCX/PDF documents unattended?

Tags: c#, powershell, pdf, printing, office-interop

I am trying to replace an outdated solution which uses Office Interop to create and print Word documents, and export them to PDF.  It needs to run unattended on a server, so we want to get rid of our dependency on Interop.  I can create the files fine with Open XML SDK but cannot print or export.  Is there some way to do this with libraries (free or paid) that does not require having Adobe/MS Office products installed in a server environment?  The limits we have to work within will allow me to either use a .NET console application or a PowerShell script.

Comment: Powershell 7.0 supports [out printer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer?view=powershell-7.2) but I can't find the supported formats.

Comment: My understanding was that Out-Printer only managed plain text.

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath “C:\Test.Docx” -Verb Print` is suggested [here](https://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/out-printer-cmdlet/) to print the default printer.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse that will  try to open the file in the default application and instruct the application to quick print so would need to have some docx compatible application installed

Comment: I found a console app called 2Printer (https://www.cmd2printer.com/) that looks like it would accomplish the task using separate processes.  I'd prefer and be curious if there were just libraries that could do the same thing.

Comment: @KJ The "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer is created when Office is installed. Since not installing Office is the whole point, this is not likely to work here.

Comment: You may check [Spire.Office for .NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/spire-office-for-net.html) which is capable of printing, editing, converting and creating Word, PDF, Excel and PowerPoint documents.

Comment: If you just need to export your documents to PDF format, you might not need the printing option. The LEADTOOLS Document Conversion SDK has the [DocumentConverter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html) class which can be used to automatically convert input files to PDF. The free evaluation (available [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads)) has a DocumentConverterFolderDemo .NET project which shows how files in a specified folder can be automatically converted to a destination output folder (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)